# Haproxy Postgresql SSL configuration

Tags: postgresql, ssl, configuration, haproxy, patroni

I need ssl connection between postgresql (patroni cluster) and Haproxy but I didnt find any related docs. Is it possible to configure haproxy via ssl without using pgbouncer or pgpool tools.

I can connect directly to the database server with ssl configuration
but I can't connect by using Haproxy,

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -d "host=x.x.x.x port=7010 dbname=postgres user=test"
psql: error: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
-bash-4.2$
```

there is no log record on postgresql.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a log record on haproxy?

Comment: Please also show the command that connects directly.

Comment: there is no log record, because log not configured, test command; -bash-4.2$ psql -d "host=x.x.x.x port=5432 dbname=postgres user=test" Password for user test: psql (12.11, server 12.12) SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off) Type "help" for help. postgres=> –

Comment: Are the x.x.x.x the same and only the port number differ?  If you 'unconfigure' ssl, can you then connect through haproxy?

Comment: No, haproxy works on different machines, so ip and port number different on haproxy test connection, I connected by server:5432 configuration and I also connected haproxyip:port without ssl config, but I could not connect after ssl configuration.

Comment: For me it "just worked" with the bare-bones configuration (TCP proxying 5431 to 5432 on the same host).  I didn't have to do anything special to get it to work over SSL.

Comment: Do you have any good documantation about haproxy-postgresql-ssl configuration. I think I did missconfiguration.
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't.  I've never used haproxy before, I just installed it with apt, did the configuration and experiment already described (both with and without ssl), then reported the result and used apt to uninstall it.